# LINQ selecting all item array elements

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

Strange question, basically I'm creating a DataTable, using the AsEnumerable() method and then using a LINQ query.

However, I don't know how many rows or columns this DataTable has, and I need to select all of the item array elements, is there any way of cycling through from ItemArray[0] to ItemArray[ItemArray.lenth-1] in a LINQ query? This is the only way I've found that can bind to an MVC grid, so if there's a better way I'd love to know!

Below is a kind of pseudocode of what i'd like to do. Any help would be great!

```
var model = from t in table.AsEnumerable().AsQueryable()
    select new
    { 
        for (i = 0 to ItemArray.length)
        {
            t.ItemArray[i]
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you post your table-class?

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you're trying to accomplish here.  A loop doesn't make sense to me in that context.  If you're building an anonymous class, what benefit does that have over just using the `DataRow` objects themselves?

Comment: Unclear. What, specifically, are you having trouble with in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *`SelectMany()`*:

```
var items = table.AsEnumerable().SelectMany(row=>row.ItemArray);
```

You can also group the items by row:

```
var items = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
            from item in row.ItemArray
            group new {item} by row;
```

Comment: This didn't really work for me, as for a table like so: `t.Columns.Add("first");
            t.Columns.Add("second");
            t.Rows.Add("1", "2");
            t.Rows.Add("1", "2");
            t.Rows.Add("1", "2");` It just gave me a table with single column of name 'column' and rows 1, 2, 1, 2 , 1, 2

Comment: I added a  grouping example.

Answer (score 0):

It does sound as if you need a `SelectMany()`, but it will be easier to read as a query expression:

```
var model = from row in table.AsEnumerable()
            from item in row.ItemArray
            select item;
```